# SharePoint survey question ordering

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to find how to access the "index" or "position" of questions in a SharePoint survey list from the object model.  I was hoping to find it with SPField.RowOrdinal but its always 0.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

```
  list.Items.Indexof(SPListItem myitem);
```

Where "list" is your SPList object; and myItem is the SPListItem you're determining the index of.

Comment: this gives me the index of the response in whole.  I need the index of the question itself on the list.